# nginx letsencrypt https redirect with express nodejs app not working

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, certbot

I need https to be the default way my site is served, I chose option 2 during letsencrypt cert generation.
I have https working on my site. It is a simple HTML page being served up by nodejs on port 3000. It is hosted in Oracle Cloud currently. I have opened the ports in iptables as Oracle does not use ufw.

If I go to https://www.example.com , the site loads securely so things are working.
If I go to http://www.example.com, the site also loads but not securely obviously.
If I go to example.com, the site loads in http, not https.

I am having trouble wrapping my mind around how I should write my nginx config file.

I need to proxy_pass using http to port 3000, but when I change the proxy_pass to https

```
proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
```

It fails to load anything and that somewhat makes sense to me because my nodejs app does not have any code to support https and I was under the impression that nginx can handle all of that for me. That line of thinking is further supported because like I said above, https://www.example.com works just fine for my site now.
Below is my config with my server name removed.  Please let me know how to best do what I am trying to accomplish.

````
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {

proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

}


  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
  if ($host = www.example.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


  if ($host = example.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;

      server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot




}```
````

Comment: Two seconds search on the Internet: https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx. BTW Your config looks strage.

Comment: @Marc That doesn't tell me how to point it to port 3000,     return 301 https://$host$request_uri; will not reach my app.

Comment: First, you redirect unsecure connections to https ones. then only your https server forward data with the proxy_pass to your node app. This is not rocket since. 1) redirect to https, 2) http server forward traffic to your node.js

Comment: @Marc wow! I got it working, I had to delete and reorder a lot of stuff, I see what you mean now that my config looks strange. Letsencrypt did almost all of it and it was out of order so I had trouble seeing the logic but I just rewrote everything and now it works and makes a lot more sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your Welcome. If possible you should answer your own question, not sure if you can do this with your low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Marc, it seems like my config was created strangely and certbot added in things slightly out of order to where it was getting confusing but I have figured it out. Like Marc said, redirect all 80 to https. In https server, make sure you have your certificates and proxy_pass there to your port 3000, or wherever your app is running.

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com;
}


server {

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
        
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

        }


}
```